# Reshape a pandas DataFrame by stacking columns

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

How do i make something like this using pandas?

```
in:
data = {post1: [like1, like2], 
        post2: [like1, like2, like3, like4], 
        post3: [like1, like2, like3]
        }

out:
post1 like1
post1 like2
post2 like1
post2 like2
post2 like3
post2 like4
post3 like1
post3 like2
post3 like3
```

I've tried this code, but it fails because lists are of different lengths. I can do it by making a lot of DataFrames and appending them but it's pretty slow.

```
def run():
    result = {}

    for link in links:
        result[link] = id2screen(get_likes(link))

    df = DataFrame.from_dict(result)
    stacked = df.set_index(keys).stack()

    stacked.to_excel(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\out.xlsx',  
                     index=False)

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

`from_dict` with `orient='index'` is more tolerant of different-length data:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
Out[32]: 
           0      1      2      3
post1  like1  like2   None   None
post3  like1  like2  like3   None
post2  like1  like2  like3  like4
```

However,

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').stack()
```

gives:

```
Out[40]: 
post1  0    like1
       1    like2
post3  0    like1
       1    like2
       2    like3
post2  0    like1
       1    like2
       2    like3
       3    like4
dtype: object
```

So to get the pictured target output, you could add `.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').stack().reset_index(level=1, 
                                                                 drop=True)
Out[34]: 
post1    like1
post1    like2
post3    like1
post3    like2
post3    like3
post2    like1
post2    like2
post2    like3
post2    like4
dtype: object
```